# Error when i do not include string header file in c++

Tags: c++, string, std

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
void main(){
string str="abc";
cout<<str;
system("pause");
}
```

If i do not include string header file then there is an error at **<<** in line cout<

I thought the error will be at line where str is defined.

Comment: Well, no. Compilers are automata, not humans. It's entirely understandable that they report an error *near* its actual location.

Comment: @H2CO3 but I think he refers to the initialization and wonders why it does not happen there...

Comment: @H2CO3 That was my interpretation as well.

Comment: `void main` is not legal. It must return `int`. Anyway, I've noticed MSVC used to be particularly fond of providing everything in `<string>` except the I/O through `<iostream>`, which is a bit ironic.

Comment: @chris: The class itself comes through the exceptions which are required by the constructor of [`ios_base::failure`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) (and perhaps some others). But I don't think other unneeded non-member functions, such as `to_string` are brought in.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Ah, I've just seen too many duplicate questions of "why can I use `string`, but not output it?"

Answer (score 10):

Standard library headers can include other standard library headers, even if not specified in the standard. So it may be that with your implementation, the `iostream` header includes some parts of the `string` header, so that `std::string` is available but `std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<...>&, const std::basic_string<...>&);` is not.