# Visual studio: E0349 no operator << matches these operands (but no strings in code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

Can't compile my code - I get: no operator “<<” matches these operands

I found similar problem [no operator "<<" matches these operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939089/no-operator-matches-these-operands), however I have no strings nor missing directives (i think)

Could someone help me please? :)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <vector>

void convBase(int base, int n);

using std::cout; 
using std::endl; 
using std::setw;
using std::vector;

int main()
{

    int numbs[] = { 61, 0, -9, -200, 9999 };
    int bases[] = { 16, 8, 2, 20, 36 };
    size_t size = sizeof(numbs) / sizeof(*numbs);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << setw(4) << numbs[i] << " = " << setw(5) 
        << convBase(numbs[i], bases[i]) << " in base " 
        << setw(2) << bases[i] << endl;
        }
    return 0;

}

void convBase(int n, int base) {
    char pierwszyZnak = 48;
    char pierwszaLitera = 65;
    vector<char> system;
    vector<char> liczba;

    for (int i = 0; i < base; i++) {
        if (i <= 9) {
            system.push_back(pierwszyZnak);
            pierwszyZnak++;
        }
        else if (i <= 36) {
            system.push_back(pierwszaLitera);
            pierwszaLitera++;
        }
        else {
            cout << "podales za duza liczbe: " << base << ". Musisz podac liczbe mniejsza badz rowna 36" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    while (n > 0) {
        int rem = n % base;
        int rem2 = floor(n / base);
        liczba.push_back(system[rem]);
        n = rem2;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = liczba.size(); i-- > 0; )
        std::cout << liczba[i];
}
```

Comment: You call `convBase` in the output, but that function doesn't return a value that can be written. It seems you need [a couple of good beginners books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) to read.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you stream a `void` to `std::cout`?

Answer (score 1):

`convBase` returns void, but you're trying to stream its return value to `std::cout`. Your function should return a string representation, silently. Return a `std::string` or `std::ostream` instead of void.

I'd suggest creating a `std::stringstream` and then streaming your output to that. You can replace the very last `std::cout` with the name of your stream, and then call its `str()` method to get the return value. (You should also make sure to verify the function behaves predictably when you give it bad characters.)